# Typescript - Is there a consistent logic behind how the engine infers and how it applies the inferrence?

Tags: typescript

Consider the below code; its clear the TS is inferring the `T` generic from `Array<{key: T}>` and the return value of `(input: Record<T, any>) => T`, while limiting the key of `Record<T, any>` to the inferred value.

So `T = one | two | three | 12345`

However, how does TS decided which is the dependent and the independent variable here? Is there some rhyme or logic to it?

```
declare function test<T extends string>(
    fragments: Array<{key: T}>, 
    func: (input: Record<T, any>) => T
): any;

test([
    {
        key: 'one'
    },
    {
        key: 'two'
    },
    {
        key: 'three'
    },
    {
        key: 'four5'
    }

   // ^^^^^^^^^^ !!!!! Can Vary Independently !!!!!!

], function(input : {
    one: 'one',
    two: 'two',
    three: 'one',
    12345: 'test'

   // ^^^^^^^^^^ !!!!! Keys are bound to other two sources !!!!!!
}){
    return '12345' // <= !!!!! Can Vary Independently !!!!!!
}
)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxAGcMAeAFXhAA9DVgj4SYtUBzAPgAoAoefpDChsAtiFQYiALngBBGEICepAN4BrEIpnkAvhwA08PgJToZXVgAdkGGQCVwOGMAqGoqRRwCU8ALwd4ch4vGXdFAG4eHkISLgBtY34VRIF+DS14AHI8EEyUnX0U5NTU9JlMjAB3HDzUgqKU0s1yjAALOFz8wtTikrTmrMQcZBgAVlqBHSiBAHoZ+AA9JeWV+ABCDY34AGF3eAA1WEV4AEl6EEtxUAkIY83NqIBdQ1NMXFQLVGsMeBle-hy5RymW6AiqOBa1RBKTaHSBqFyoP4AEYAEwAZgALKMWsQMHlEnNFisSet7vAANKaRiwBCgS7nCTwPDMtogGAEapMYYwMDEMn3Hg6Lz-eBwDAjfCZNFY8bwImkXwCra7fCHGDHM70q7iDC3ZUbIXBIA)

Comment: There are a lot of heuristics involved in inferring generic type parameters; I think there is an order of priority of inference site locations; you tend to get inference for those usages at the highest priority and then the ones with lower priority are checked against it.  Not sure I can find a canonical description of this process that's both explanatory and still current.  I'll keep looking

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the language evolves faster than they can keep an up-to-date language specification, so they stopped doing it. [This section of the outdated language spec document](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b5bab16a962dd6e02fe65f6d5eb5a0de11cb9d5b/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#4.15.2) explains how such inference was done at some earlier version of the language.